# Daterangepicker is Not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This my jQuery code in WordPress site. Its works well but when I run in a modal the for-each loop its not works. I saw other answers but I can't understand.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
             jQuery(function() {
                 jQuery('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
                     autoUpdateInput: false,
                     locale: {
                         cancelLabel: 'Cancel'
                     }
                 });
                 jQuery('#datepicker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                     $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
                 });
                 jQuery('#datepicker').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                     jQuery(this).val('');
                 });
             });
```

**Form**

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $row) 
    {   ?>

            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label>Check-in / Out</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="datefilter" placeholder="Check-in / Out">
                </div>
            </form>


        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to add `class` instead of `id`

Comment: @Agam Banga  stil its not working in modal

Comment: The issue may be is with z-index of the datepicker. It maybe hidden behind the modal. You can check it in Chrome Dev Tools  to see if its showing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the daterangepicker using id of the element, you can use a common class for all the daterangepicker elements and call the daterangepicker